# How to find nearby places using new places sdk for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to apply the new library that android added after 29,January 2019. All the old apps are using maps and places sdk are their methods are deprecated. I have tried to read all the new docs but it seems that the new library doesn't support nearby search but only current location. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: Check this link once https://stackoverflow.com/a/57832796/12018179

Comment: Does still exist the option to find places by text search, ex: strings. I want to find locations nearby when user types in "gym", "bank" etc?

Comment: There is an existing feature request(https://issuetracker.google.com/133276015)  to add the Nearby Search for Places SDK for Android.  You can star the link to add your vote and receive further updates regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code would be an example you can use for guidance of how you can call the Nearby Search service from the [Java client](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) within your Android app:

MapsActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.maps.model.PlacesSearchResult;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private Context mContext;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        PlacesSearchResult[] placesSearchResults = new NearbySearch().run().results;

        Log.e("response1Tag", placesSearchResults[0].toString());
        Log.e("response2Tag", placesSearchResults[1].toString());

        double lat1 = placesSearchResults[0].geometry.location.lat;
        double lng1 = placesSearchResults[0].geometry.location.lng;

        double lat2 = placesSearchResults[1].geometry.location.lat;
        double lng2 = placesSearchResults[1].geometry.location.lng;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat2, lng2)));

        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(14.0f);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat1, lng1)));
    }
}
```

NearbySearch.java

```
import com.google.maps.GeoApiContext;
import com.google.maps.PlacesApi;
import com.google.maps.errors.ApiException;
import com.google.maps.model.PlaceType;
import com.google.maps.model.PlacesSearchResponse;
import com.google.maps.model.RankBy;
import com.google.maps.model.LatLng;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NearbySearch {

    public PlacesSearchResponse run(){
        PlacesSearchResponse request = new PlacesSearchResponse();
        GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                .apiKey("MY_KEY")
                .build();
        LatLng location = new LatLng(-33.8670522, 151.1957362);

        try {
            request = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, location)
                    .radius(5000)
                    .rankby(RankBy.PROMINENCE)
                    .keyword("cruise")
                    .language("en")
                    .type(PlaceType.RESTAURANT)
                    .await();
        } catch (ApiException | IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

In build.gradle add:

```
implementation 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.11.0'
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Note that the API key you'll use to call the API should be secured properly, e.g. you may need to set up a proxy server. Take a look at [these techniques](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#api_key_table_sup_5).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks good, however, when I try to add the current location of the user it gives an error that I use google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng instead of google.maps.model.LatLng. It seems that this lib does not support current location function

Comment: I want them to add on map but the latlng is not compatible with android's latlng

Comment: Oh I see, let me have a look at this and get back to you.

Comment: Heya @Marin sorry for taking so long, I'm finally able to look into this today :)

Comment: @Marin Please check out my edit. Hoping this is what you wanted! :)

Comment: thanks for your help bro, however it does not show for me same as for you. For me, there are no nearby places. Anyways, I managed to do that ;). Now I am trying to show routes between the current place and the nearby places. So far no luck/ If you could give me a hand on that, please let me know. Cheers!

Comment: Not sure I understood what you meant but I'm glad anyway that you were able to get it to work, glad to have been of help! :) As for your new question, please do post is a new question and I'll answer you if no one else beats me to it haha.

Comment: Oh.. how come? :O

Comment: @evan I am not able to use restricted api key (secured using package name & SHA1), any help on this ? We can not used secured api key in place API but in places android SDK we should because we are using its SDK rather than simple API.